# Concat and get all matching nested arrays across entire collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have question, in database I have model :

board.model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var BoardSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, maxlength: 20 },
  lists : { type: Array },
  users : [{ type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],    
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Board', BoardSchema);
```

Inside **lists** is added array cards. 
In practice it looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22a"),
    "name" : "1",
    "users" : [ 
        ObjectId("59cd114cea98d9326ca1c421")
    ],
    "lists" : [ 
        {
            "list" : "1",
            "cards" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "1",
                    "Author" : [ 
                     ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22a")
                    ],
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "2" 
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "3" 
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "list" : "2",
            "cards" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "1",
                    "Author" : [ 
                     ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22a")
                    ],
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "2",
                    "Author" : [ 
                     ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22a")
                    ],
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "3" 
                }
            ]
        } 
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Okay this is an example of one board, the question is can I pull only the cards in which the author is "Author": ObjectId ("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22a") of all boards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in 3.4.

Concat all the matching (`$filter`) cards in each board followed by `$unwind` and push to collect all cards across boards.

Breakdown:

`$reduce` to concat all the cards arrays in a single document.

`$filter` operates on `$$this` ( `cards` array ) arguments and filters for matching cards while `$$value` keeps the previous values.

`$concatArrays` to merge the previous values with the current filtered values.

`$unwind` to deconstruct cards arrays and `$group` with `$push` to get all cards arrays across boards.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "boardcards": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$lists.cards",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$$this",
                  "as": "result",
                  "cond": {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$result.Author",
                      ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22a")
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$boardcards"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "allboardcards": {
        "$push": "$boardcards"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

As asked in the comment to get just the names of cards you have to wrap the `$filter` in `$map` operator to only map card names.

So replace `$filter` with `$map` + `$filter`

```
{
  "$map": {
    "input": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$$this",
        "as": "result",
        "cond": {
          "$eq": [
            "$$result.Author",
           ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22a")
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "as": "result",
    "in": {
      "name": "$$result.name"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Np. Couple of things - 1. Change `collection` to name of your collection like `db.<collection_name>.aggregate(...)`; 2. Run  the query in mongo shell. 3. Replace `db.<collection_name>.aggregate` with `Board.aggregate(..)` to execute in mongoose.

Comment: Hey in result what will I get??, I did not make such complex queries, Will I have only card names?

Comment: You will have cards array with whole card element.  Do you just need the names ?

Comment: No, I need whole card element with array is ok, but If I also need the name of the board, what now??

Comment: Edited answer to include more explanation and added update when you just want names.

Comment: Hey sorry, I mean name board, not cards :(

Comment: Np.That is trivial. Add `name:1` in `$project` stage to include field in the output.

Comment: ok, i'm learning it, then i'll let you know if it worked :) thanks

Comment: hey Veeram can u look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959242/extracting-from-the-base-results-mongodb Can i first download list boards where _idboard == req.user._id and next with this list demarcated second array with boards where idboard == req.user.favorites(array of ids boards which i make favorite) ?? so in one result 2arrays